# Connecting to multiple server hubs from browser with SignalR

Tags: signalr

I have started with [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) basic tutorial for SignalR and its working fine. 
As a next step in my learning, I added one more Hub on the server which looks as follows. I intend to send server time to clients.

```
public class ServerTimeHub : Hub
{
    public void SendServerTime()
    {
        do
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Clients.All.BroadCastServerTime(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        } while (true);
    }
}
```

Now in the client html I have added this line in javascript

```
var time = $.connection.serverTimeHub;
```

and the following line in $.connection.hub.start().done function.

```
time.server.sendServerTime();
```

So the entire java script function looks like the following.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
        var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
        // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
        chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
            // Html encode display name and message.
            var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
            var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();
            // Add the message to the page.
            $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName
                + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
        };
        // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
        $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
        // Set initial focus to message input box.
        $('#message').focus();

        var time = $.connection.serverTimeHub;
        time.client.broadCastServerTime = function (currentTime) {
            $('#TimeSpan').text(currentTime);
        }

        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            // THE FOLLOWING IS THE ADDITIONAL LINE
            time.server.sendServerTime(); 
            $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                // Call the Send method on the hub.
                chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
                $('#message').val('').focus();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

My problem is, both the hubs are not getting called. Only one is getting called. If I want ChatHub to be called, then I am forced to comment out the

```
time.server.sendServerTime();
```

inside the $.connection.hub.start().done function.

Just trying to understand why two methods are not called and only one is called. Please help.